# When creating a child Table in Rails, do you have to specify the parent key, or will the association do that automatically for you?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can't believe I still don't know this... if I am creating a new table `Fruit` belonging to parent `Basket`, do I have to write this in the migration file:

```
create_table :fruits do |t|
  t.integer :basket_id
  ...
end
```

Or is it enough to do this:

```
create_table :fruits do |t|
  t.belongs_to :basket
  ...
end
```

Of course, the model files will be set up appropriately:

```
class Fruit
  belongs_to :basket
end

class Basket
  has_many :fruits
end
```

Or does it depend on version and/or circumstance (e.g., there are actually fundamental differences to one way or the other, for example, I can see where if you specify `belongs_to` in the table, then maybe rails automatically creates a validation: `validates :basket_id, presence: true` for `Fruit`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a `has_many`, `belongs_to` association, in the table/migration for the `belongs_to`, you do need to somehow tell it to store the `has_many` id.

In your example, in the fruit table/migration, you have to tell it you need the basket_id. There are a few ways to do this. You've already discovered two of them:

```
t.integer :basket_id
t.belongs_to :basket_id
```

There is also a third way:

```
t.references :basket
```

They all do pretty much the same thing. As long as you have the basket_id in the fruits table/migration, you'll be fine.

Another thing you might want to do, if it wasn't already done with the migration, is add a foreign_key. You can do that by adding `foreign_key: true`:

```
t.references :basket, foreign_key: true
```

This will tell the fruit table that the `basket_id` is a foreign_key, essentially a key from another table (the basket table).

Comment: but like, can you use one method to the exclusion of the others, is what i'm trying to understand. if i run a migration with `t.belongs_to :basket` does that, due to rails magic, automatically add the `basket_id` key, or do i still need a line in the migration that says `t.integer :basket_id`

Comment: That line will add the basket_id to the fruit table. You can also double check this by looking at your `schema.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/88aa2efd692619e87eee88dfc48d608bea9bcdb4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L421) belongs_to is actually an alias of references.

In Rails 5, whenever we define a belongs_to association, it is required to have the associated record present by default. Though there are ways to turn this off.

To turn off this behaviour for a particular association:

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

To turn off for entire application:

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```

This can be added in application.rb file.

You can go through this [article](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html) to understand better.

However in Rails 4 for example even if you add t.belongs_to model validation won't be there by default. You need to add have:

```
belongs_to :user, required: true
```

`belongs_to` or `references` are there for foreign key constraints and database integrity not for model validations.